# Is it natural to use "last for a long time" to describe a meeting?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I was having a phone call with one of my friends.

> Friend: How about we hang out together this Saturday?

> I: Sunday is better, because I have a meeting in Saturday morning which will probably **last for a long time**.

Is my response clear and natural? I meant if the meeting will be finished in one hour, we can hang out on Saturday. But the meeting is probably longer than that and it's inappropriate to have my friend wait me for that long.

Are there any other expressions more natural I could use in the context?

Comment: _Go on for a long time_ would probably be more idiomatic, but _last_ isn't wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is clear and natural. There are alternatives, all of which depend on your perception of probability.

Will probably last ... reads as if you think the probability is high

Will possibly last ... reads as if there is a chance of lasting but you do not know if the chance is high or low

Is likely to last ... (=more likely than not) reads as if you think the probability is higher than 50%

Might last ... admits the chance of lasting but says nothing about the likelihood.